# Will Paginate: Limit number of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

Im using the will paginate gem for ruby. I am using will paginate to get a bunch of people and sorting on a field. What I want is only the first 100 of those. Essentially the top people. I cant seeem to do this. How would i go about it? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
people = Person.limit(100).paginate(:per_page => 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as my knowledge goes will_paginate doesn't provide an option for this, I just had a root around in its source too to check, but if you don't mind having a subquery in your conditions it can be done...

```
people = Person.paginate(page: 10).where('people.id IN (SELECT id FROM people ORDER BY a_field LIMIT 100)').per_page(5)
people.total_pages
=> 20
```

Replace a_field with the field your sorting on, and this should work for you.

(note, the above uses the current version of will_paginate (3.0.2) for its syntax, but the same concept applies to older version as well using the options hash)

Comment: Hey. This will give me 100 per page? I want 5 on a page. But only the first 100.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, no problem, I have edited my original answer to fit your needs :)

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

`will_paginate` gem will take `total_entries` parameter to limit the number of entries to paginate.

```
@problems = Problem.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10, 
total_entries: 30)
```

This gives you 3 pages of 10 records each.