# Ruby on Rails - Search, Order, Limit then Paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I want to have a search function for the data. After search, then order by a column and then limit the results to 200 only. Finally paginate with will_paginate.

My Controller

```
  def search
    title = params[:title]
    company = params[:company]
    location_id = params[:location_id]
    page = params[:page]
    @wages = Wage.search(title, company, location_id,page)
  end
```

My model

def self.search(title, company, location_id, page)
    if location_id.present?

```
    paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id],
                    :order => "total DESC",
                    :page => page,
                    :per_page => 20                       
else

    paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%"],
                    :order => "total DESC",
                    :page => page,
                    :per_page => 20                                                                    
end
```

end

I tried changing to the below code in order to limit the result:

```
paginate :conditions => ['title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%"].limit(200)
```

But it is not working. What is a best way to do it?

Comment: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424562/ruby-on-rails-pagination-on-search-result), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442490/why-is-pagination-on-search-result-not-working) and this.

Answer (score 0):

Checking with this other question [will-paginate-limit-number-of-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620978/will-paginate-limit-number-of-results) seems that you can do something like this:

```
wages = Wage.limit(100).paginate(:per_page => 5)
```

In your case (I haven't tested it, but I think that it can work):

```
@wages = Wage.where('title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%").limit(200).paginate(:per_page => 20, :order => "total DESC", :page => page)
```

In this case `@wages` is a `will_paginate` object:

```
@wages.total_pages
=> 20
```

Or you can render with the `html_helpers` of `will_paginate` in the view ([API-documentation#view-template-helpers](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#view-template-helpers)).

```
# controller
@wages = Wage.where('title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%").limit(200)
# you should have @wages.count = 200

# view
<%= will_paginate @wages, :style => 'color:blue' %>
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach as mentioned in the other answer. But the **.limit(200)** function didn't perform as it still show all data.

Comment: @NgYatPing sound a little strange, the second example is a simple query only + will_paginate, can you count it (edit my answer)? Are you sure that the params passed to the query are what you want? Try only the query stand alone

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
class Wage < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 10

  def self.search(title, company, location_id, page)

    if location_id     
      wages = Wage.where('title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id).order('total DESC').limit(200).paginate(:page => page)
    else
      wages = Wage.where('title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%").order('total DESC').limit(200).paginate(:page => page)
    end
    return wages
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can pass in "total_entries" to your paginate method, as shown:

```
wages = Wage.where('title LIKE ? AND company LIKE ? AND location_id = ?', "%#{title}%", "%#{company}%", location_id).order('total DESC').paginate(:page => page, :total_entries => 200)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should make sure you have any data that matches the search terms for BOTH title AND company. The code should work just fine.

Comment: I change the code a bit. It perform the search well but the **.limit(200)** function didn't work. It still show all data.

Comment: limit method, provided by Rails' ActiveRecord, should work. You can look at your Rails log to see the actual query and notice that the SQL the method generates should include "LIMIT 200". WHat is your DB implementation? SQLite3, MySQL, or PG? Nonetheless, I edited my answer to show some other way, which is using "total_entries".